# Assign a variable a value from an array - pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal

I have an array and I wish to assign the value of part of the array to a string, however, I get an error:

> Left side cannot be assigned to

when I do this:

```
(s):=(Array[1]);
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Isn't `array` a keyword in Pascal? Wait, this is not the real code; right. Can you show the real code? And the definition of the string?

Comment: i'm sorry, at the moment my code is a mess and this is the easiest way to display it. The string is actually called temp and the array resultArray
(temp):=(resultArray[i]); {the 'i' variable is selected through a for loop}

i am not sure what you mean by definition of the string

Comment: What's up with all the parentheses? What error did you see exactly? How is `Array` defined (and `Array` is a keyword, so you shouldn't be using it as a variable name).

Answer (score 3):

This is a feature (or bug?) of all 32/64-bit Delphi versions I tested. Even a minimal complete program like

```
program test;
var
  s: string;
begin
  (s) := 'a';
  writeln(s);
end.
```

will not compile without this error. No problems with Turbo/Borland, Virtual, or Free Pascal (even in Delphi mode). I assume that the Delphis treat `(s)` as an expression, which can **have** a value but you cannot **assign** a value to it.
Of course if you write  `s := 'a';` Delphi works as expected.

BTW: I consider it a bad habit, that you put superfluous `()` around variables and expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I'd assume that to assign to something it has to be a single pointer to an address to fill. There's no need to bracket a single pointer so the compiler complains that it's a complex construct that cannot be assigned to. This is for all data types, not just strings.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bumping an old thread here, but I believe that you should first declare your array.
If the variable `Array` is considered a string then the output of `Array[1]` would be the first character of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  ....

```
Var
    myVar   : Integer;
    myArray : Array[1..5] of Integer;

Begin
 myArray[2] := 25;
 myVar := myArray[2];
End.
```

Reference: http://pascal-programming.info/lesson10.php